# setting an initial value in app-indexedb-mirror

Tags: javascript, polymer, behavior

Anyone know how to overide the `zeroValue` getter in `app-indexedb-mirror` element? I want my database to have an initial value when its empty, but when i set the elements `zero-value` property, it doesnt update. The `app-indexedb-mirror` itself inherits the `zeroValue` function from a behavior.

Here is a section of my element setup.

```
<template>
    <content>
            <app-indexeddb-mirror id="plUserData" key="plUserData" data="{{plUserData}}" persisted-data="{{plUserPersistedData}}" log="true" zero-value="{{zeroValue}}"></app-indexeddb-mirror> 
    </content>
    </template>
  <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
            Polymer({
                is: "pl-user",
                behaviors: [
                    Polymer.AppStorageBehavior
                ],
                properties: {
                    zeroValue: {
                        type: Object,
                        value: {
                                        loginData: [{
                                            welcomeMsg: "Hi there!", 
                                            signinMsg: "Sign in to continue...", 
                                            btnAction: "Create an account",
                                            selected: "username"
                                        }]
                                     }
                    },
                    plUserData: { 
                        type: Object
                    },
                    plUserPersistedData: {
                        type: Object
                    }
                },
                ready(){
                    this.select = 'sign-in';

                }
            });
        });
  </script>
```